# Implementing `MyMonad Free f`

Tags: haskell

Typeclassopedia defines the `Free monad` data type.

> data Free f a = Var a
>                  | Node (f (Free f a))

Given:

```
class (MyMonad m) where
    ret     :: a         -> m a
    flatMap :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Here's my incomplete attempt at implementing the `MyMonad` instance of this typeclass.

```
instance Functor f => MyMonad (Free f) where
  ret                 = Var
  flatMap (Var x)  f  = f x 
  flatMap (Node xs) f = error
```

Please help me reason about what `>>=`/binding means over a `Free` monad.

When I struggled with [implementing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27527703/implementing-applicative-free-f) `Applicative (Free f)`, I was encouraged to try to implement the `Monad` instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In these kinds of situations, [typed holes](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/typed-holes.html) can help with how to proceed. They give information about the type the still unimplemented "hole" should have.

Using a typed hole instead of `error` in your definition:

```
instance Functor f => MyMonad (Free f) where
    ret                 = Var
    flatMap (Var x)  g  = f x
    flatMap (Node xs) g = _
```

Gives an error message like (here simplified):

```
Found hole `_' with type: Free f b
...
Relevant bindings include
  g :: a -> Free f b (bound at Main.hs:10:21)
  xs :: f (Free f a) (bound at Main.hs:10:17)
  flatMap :: Free f a -> (a -> Free f b) -> Free f b
    (bound at Main.hs:9:3)
```

That `Free f b` in the hole... which constructor should it have? `Var` or `Node`?

Now, a value of type `Free a` is like a tree that has values of type `a` on the leaves (the `Var` constructor) and whose branching nodes are "shaped" by the functor `f`.

What is `>>=` for `Free`? Think of it as taking a tree and "grafting" new trees on each of its leaves. These new trees are constructed from the values in the leaves using the function that is passed to `>>=`.

This helps us continue: now we know that the constructor on the right of the   `flatMap (Node xs) f = _` pattern must be `Node`, because "grafting" new things onto the tree never collapses already existing nodes into leaves, it only expands leaves into whole new trees.

Still using type holes:

```
instance Functor f => MyMonad (Free f) where
    ret                 = Var
    flatMap (Var x)  g  = f x
    flatMap (Node xs) g = Node _

Found hole `_' with type: f (Free f b)
...
Relevant bindings include
g :: a -> Free f b (bound at Main.hs:10:21)
xs :: f (Free f a) (bound at Main.hs:10:17)
```

In `xs` we have a `Free f a` wrapped in a `f`, but `f` is a functor and we could easily map over it.

But how to convert that `Free f a` into the `Free f b` required by the hole? Intuitively, this `Free f a` will be "smaller" that the one the `>>=` started with, because we have stripped one "branching node". Maybe it is even a leaf node, like the case covered by the other pattern-match! This suggests using recursion of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Start by implementing the `Functor` instance. Then note that in general, a monad can be described as a functor that supports `return` and `join :: m (m a) -> m a`. Can you see how to implement `join` using `=<<` and `return`? Can you see how to implement `=<<` using `fmap` and `join`?

#### Spoilers

As you indicated,

```
data Free f a = Var a | Node (f (Free f a))
```

So (as you could work out with typed holes)

```
join :: Functor f => Free f (Free f a) -> Free f a
join (Var a) = a
join (Node m) = Node (fmap join m)
```

It might be useful to think about the geometry here. We descend the tree recursively, leaving the structure the same, until we get to the leaves, which we unwrap.

Note: `=<<` is the flipped version of `>>=`; it's more consistent with the other composition operators. `$`, `<$>`, `<*>`, `.`, `=<<`, and `<=<` all match up so you can read an expression using them from left to right or right to left without having to switch directions a few times in the middle.