# Decision Tree in haskell defining >>= and return

Tags: haskell, tree, monads

I'm trying to make a Decision Tree for a game and I have:

```
data DecisionTree a
   = Result a
   | Decision [DecisionTree a]
   deriving (Eq,Show)`
```

furthermore, I have

```
instance Functor DecisionTree where
    fmap = liftM
```

now I have to define

```
instance Monad DecisionTree where
-- return :: a -> DecisionTree a
   return = ...
-- (>>=) :: DecisionTree a -> (a -> DecisionTree b) -> DecisionTree b
   (>>=) = ...
```

Now I'm kinda confused how to fill in the definitions.

To define `>>=` I tried splitting the definition into two cases:

```
(>>=) (Result a) f    = f a
(>>=) (Decision ys) f = Decision (fmap (>>= f) ys)
```

As for `return` I thought at least something like

```
return = Result
```

but this only builds `Result a` and no `Decision [DecisionTree a]`.

Am I completely off or am I close?

Comment: Please use proper block-markdown for code blocks (as I edited it now). The easiest way to do this is to select the code blocks and press `ctrl+k`.

Comment: There is in general not _one right way_ to define a monad instance. It depends on what behaviour you want / how you plan to use these trees. Your ideas aren't “completely off”, but whether they're right I can't say without further information.

Comment: If I'm looking at it correctly, `DecisionTree` is isomorphic to `Free []` (that is, [`Control.Monad.Free`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.1/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html) from the `free` package). In that case, what `(>>=)` does is to substitute each `Result` in the decision tree with a whole new tree constructed from the result's value. See this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413797/implementing-mymonad-free-f

Comment: It looks to me like if your if `f` produces a `Decision [DecisionTree a]` you can also build that kind of substructure. What is the problem exactly? Are you not sure if the monad laws are fulfilled, do you get errors, are the results not what you expected?

Comment: I decided to check what was not functioning properly by just plugging in some values and see what the results are and they were what I wanted. So I decided to go on and use it in my next function to simulate tossing a coin and rolling a dice and apparantly it does function the way I intended. Thanks for the added information, I think it helped me understand more what I was doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [free monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.1/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html) for `[]`. As such, while there may be multiple ways to define a monad instance (per @leftroundabout), there is one canonical way to define a free monad instance, which is the one you have chosen. (You can compare your implementation to that of `Free` and see that they are equivalent. The only difference is that you fix the choice of `f` to `[]`.)

> but this only builds `Result a` and no `Decision [DecisionTree a]`.

I'm not sure what this means, but an arrow `a -> DecisionTree b` that produces a `Decision` will produce a `Decision`. `return` will always produce a `Result`, but that is expected.

Comment: Accepting this, since this combined with the comments made me find the solution (which was in fact what I had already, but somehow it gave some problems).